# How to force Internet Explorer to respect Content-Type on JavaScript reload

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, http-headers

In some case a HTTP request cannot be processed (timeout, quota, ...), and so we display a warning by sending an HTML page as HTTP response, with proper `Content-Type: text/html`.

This HTML page have a button which use JavaScript `location.reload()` to try again original request, replaying the whole original request (same parameters, URL, method [GET, POST, HEAD, ...]). If this time the request can be performed, the expected response is served with its headers (e.g. `Content-Type: application/pdf`).

This reload is working in standard-friendly browsers such as Firefox, Chrome/Safari, but not in Internet Explorer (9/10/11) which is displaying the reloaded content but ignores the `Content-Type` header of this 'reloaded' response, and keep considering it as HTML (`Content-Type` of the temporary warning page).

I have tried adding the `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff` but it doesn't fix IE issue.

Is there any way to make IE respect response headers in this case?

Comment: You could try this location.href = location.href. It's basically the same, but can make a difference.

Comment: That's absolutely not the same. This will send a different GET request to the URL or original request, without original parameters and not using the same HTTP method as the original request (could be POST, HEAD, ...).

Comment: True, this only works with a get of course.

Comment: Isn't IE trying to load this out of it's cache?

Comment: No. IE default for `location.reload` is not to use cache, moreover, the content change is displayed in the browser, with no respect for the `Content-Type` header causing critical display issues.

Comment: Related bug report found at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/264868

Comment: How about if you try "application/x-pdf"?

Comment: As said, issue is not the `Content-Type` string, but that IE is not considering at all this header in this kind.